# Can you update a table using a partition within the where clause?

Tags: sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partitioning

I have a query:

```
SELECT *, ORDER = MAX(ORDER) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
FROM MY TABLE
```

Where MY_TABLE is currently

| ID | ORDER | AGE | RECENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 | TRUE |
| 99 | 41 | 17 | TRUE |
| 12 | 34 | 24 | TRUE |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 15 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 38 | TRUE |

I want the table to be updated as the result from the query to be

| ID | ORDER | AGE | RECENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 | TRUE |
| 99 | 41 | 17 | FALSE |
| 12 | 34 | 24 | TRUE |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 15 | FALSE |
| 12 | 33 | 38 | FALSE |

Is there a way to do this with an UPDATE statement.

I was trying

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET RECENT = FALSE
WHERE ORDER <> MAX(ORDER) OVER (PARTITION BY ID);
```

But I am not sure how to incorporate the partition statement into the update.

Comment: I suggest _not_ doing this update.  Just run your select whenever you need to view the output above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update my_table
set recent = false
where (id, order) not in (select id, max(order) from my_table group by 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen, running this as an update may not be the best idea. Rather than updating the table you could create a view over the top of it to always show the latest information, without needing to update the table. This removes the risk of the `RECENT` column going out of date between new values being added, and the update process being executed.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_tbl (id NUMBER, "ORDER" NUMBER, age NUMBER);

INSERT INTO my_tbl VALUES 
(12, 34, 50),
(99, 41, 17),
(12, 34, 24),
(99, 42, 12),
(12, 33, 15),
(12, 33, 38);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT
    *,
    "ORDER" = MAX("ORDER") OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS RECENT
FROM
    my_tbl
;
```

This gives the output:

| ID | ORDER | AGE | RECENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 | TRUE |
| 99 | 41 | 17 | FALSE |
| 12 | 34 | 24 | TRUE |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 15 | FALSE |
| 12 | 33 | 38 | FALSE |

Adding another row:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_tbl VALUES (12, 35, 51);
```

Gives:

| ID | ORDER | AGE | RECENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | 50 | FALSE |
| 99 | 41 | 17 | FALSE |
| 12 | 34 | 24 | FALSE |
| 99 | 42 | 12 | TRUE |
| 12 | 33 | 15 | FALSE |
| 12 | 33 | 38 | FALSE |
| 12 | 35 | 51 | TRUE |